# A Question about good Design (.NET, System.Windows.Form.Button, C#)

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

I was wondering about a smart way to solve the following scenario:

I want to implement an onscreen keyboard with `System.Windows.Form`. There are a lot of buttons functions to implement and I don't really want to write a callback function for every single button, since they basically all do the same.

Where do I store the 'character' information in the button object, in a solid way, without using too much of a hack?

Or.. generally, can you show me some better approaches to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tag property of the Button is a good place to store information.

[Control.Tag Property via MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Inherit from `Button` such that you can provide (probably in the constructor) the character code that the button represents. Use that button.

Alternatively, since the button will show it's character in the button text, just get the button text to find out what has been pressed.

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying, but I failed. The problem is, at least Visual Studio (maybe .NET) does not recognize that my Button-subclass is, well, still a Button.

Comment: You would have to change the type of the variable in the '*.Designer.cs' file, too.

Comment: hmm.. that's where I changed it in the first place. I couldn't find where to change the button class in the form designer itself. (in the element properties, I assumed)

Comment: @Efrain: No, none of that. Your custom button subclass must inherit from `System.Windows.Forms.Button`. Once you've done that, it will get a "component" icon in the toolbox, and you'll be able to add it to your toolbox manually. Right-click on an empty space in the toolbox and click "Choose Items". Alternatively, turn on "AutoToolboxPopulate" in the Options -> Windows Forms Designer preferences.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of on screen keyboards out there for WPF already, might want to take a look at those.  If you don't want to use them directly, they may at least point you in a direction:

http://wosk.codeplex.com/

http://wpfkb.codeplex.com/